# How to Call WebReqeuest.Create on a Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, webrequest

Hi guys i have this code to be created  as a  web service, the problem is with WebRequest.Create, it seems that a web service doesn't  have a create method, what can I do as a workaround? thanks. Here's my entire code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;



namespace ApplicationMonitoring.Service
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebRequest
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebRequest : System.Web.Services.WebService 
    {

    [WebMethod]
    public string WebReq(string url,int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("10.80.50.60:8080", true);
            request.Timeout = timeout;
            //request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // execute the request
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            response.StatusCode.ToString();

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode);

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);` creates a webService.

you can refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Here is the code to create an instance of webRequest.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
      public static void Main ()
      {
        // Create a request for the URL.        
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Cleanup the streams and the response.
        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
       }
     }
   }
```

now to create a webService request you just have to use the

`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);`
make sure you have included required header file.

Comment: hi, i need to be able to send a webrequest to a specific url to check its status, whether its up and running or not, my problem is  'Test.Service.WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Create'.

Comment: hi, im using a web service class, and my problem is with the Webrequest not having a create method. ive already added the Using System.Net but still no method of create appears. heres my header public class WebRequest : System.Web.Services.WebService {}

Comment: I think you have to use system.Net.webRequest and System.Net.HttpWebRequest for the task

Comment: hi ajeet, ive updated my code section above, its a .asmx.cs file

Comment: I will say just remove this line ` : System.Web.Services.WebService` from your above code and add the above headers I mentioned.